# General programming questions are not a good fit for gamedev

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, policy

Programming questions about game-related engines/frameworks/library API are welcome. Another reason to ask here is when one thinks that a professional game developer would give a better/different/more specific answer to the question than other programmers.

Otherwise, general programming questions more likely belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead of here. This includes programming questions about:

- language API (e.g., how to use a `list` or a `vector` in your favourite language),
- compiler errors, linker errors, runtime errors or exceptions,
- general networking strategies,
- language construct optimization,
- etc.

As usual, some questions will be borderline, and we expect the community to vote to close them as they think.

---

This is based on past discussions:

- [Have we abandoned the rule about generic programming questions?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/have-we-abandoned-the-rule-about-generic-programming-questions)
- [Generic programming questions are off-topic, period. Right?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/generic-programming-questions-are-off-topic-period-right)
- [Do we still consider programming questions off topic if the context is game-dev related, but the problem turned out to be generic?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/do-we-still-consider-programming-questions-off-topic-if-the-context-is-game-dev)
- [Programming Questions: Here or "Belongs on Stackoverflow"?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow)
- [This question's revisions](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2852/revisions)